# How can hwinfo find disks that lsblk can't and that don't show up as a /dev/sdXY?

Tags: usb, disk

I recently ran into a situation where my kernel was missing a module necessary for accessing an external USB hard drive. The drive wasn't found by lsblk and didn't have a /dev/sdXY but strangely `hwinfo --disk` was still able to find it.

How does hwinfo search for disks and why can it find things that other tools miss? (I figured all these sorts of tools were just munging through the /dev filesystem in a very similar manner.)

Comment: `hwinfo --disk`should give you the answer. Not recognized as `block`device? As you said the kernel module was missing, so how could the kernel know much about the device?

Comment: @ridgy Add some details and this is a good answer. (e.g. how can I tell from the hwinfo output that something isn't recognized as a block device?
 how can hwinfo know that something is a disk if the kernel doesn't recognize it as a block device?)

Comment: I am not an expert for hwinfo. But there are some sources for information: `hwinfo --dump-db 1`shows the content of the internal hardware database, which contains lots of information depending on device classes etc. For a removable device, you can run `dmesg -w` before attaching it, to see what information the kernel gets. Maybe from some of the device information (and maybe from the database) `hwinfo` gets the `Hardware class: disk` information. The device information itself seems to depend on the driver module, so there might be no device information (can't test, have no device not working).

Comment: I digged a bit deeper, and when you run `hwinfo | less` you will see that there are lots of subsystems asked for information. Especially `udevinfo` shows full device information, and with some of them there are entries `...FROM_DATABASE..`.

Comment: @ridgy Good find. This is plenty good for an answer. I didn't mean to give the impression that I wanted a line-by-line explanation of the hwinfo source. hwinfo just happened to be the tool where I saw this behavior but I wanted to know in general how it's possible for a tool to do this and you've explained that.